Tangent developable is locally isometric to an open set in ℝ²
I'm trying to solve this problem about tangent developable from a differential geometry exam $\sf 1996\ Q3$:

My working:
First part

$\ldots\ldots$deduce that $Σ$ is ruled (that is, each point of $Σ$ is contained in a straight line segment which lies in $Σ$).

Since the second fundamental form is $L d u^2$, we have
$$\frac{∂ }{∂ v}⋅\frac{∂ }{∂ u}=-⋅\frac{∂^2 }{∂ u∂ v}=0\\
\frac{∂ }{∂ v}⋅\frac{∂ }{∂ v}=-⋅\frac{∂^2 }{∂ v^2}=0$$
so $\frac{∂}{∂ v} =0$, so $$ is independent of the coordinate $v$.
$$\frac{∂}{∂ v}(\frac{∂ }{∂ u})=\frac{∂}{∂ u}(\frac{∂ }{∂ v})=\frac{∂}{∂ u}(0)=0$$
so $\frac{∂ }{∂ u}$ is independent of the coordinate $v$.
Using $\left|\frac{∂ }{∂ u}×\frac{∂ }{∂ v}\right|=\sqrt{EG}$
$$
 × \frac{∂ }{∂ u}=\frac{\frac{∂ }{∂ u}×\frac{∂ }{∂ v}}{\sqrt{EG}}×\frac{∂ }{∂ u}=\frac{(\frac{∂ }{∂ u}⋅\frac{∂ }{∂ u})\frac{∂ }{∂ v}-(\frac{∂ }{∂ v}⋅\frac{∂ }{∂ u})\frac{∂ }{∂ u}}{\sqrt{EG}}=\frac{-L\frac{∂ }{∂ v}}{\sqrt{EG}}
$$
so $ψ=\frac{L}{\sqrt{EG}}$.
Consider the curve $γ(v)=(u_0,v)$ for constant $u_0$. We proved $ψ \frac{∂ }{∂ v}$ is independent of $v$, so the direction of tangent vector $γ'(v)=\frac{∂ }{∂ v}(u_0,v)$ is constant, so $γ$ is a straight line.
Second part

Let $γ: ℝ → ℝ^3$ be a smooth curve with $\left|γ'(t)\right|=1$, and such that $γ''$ is nowhere zero. Let $Σ$ be the surface with parametrisation
$$
(t, v)=γ(t)+v γ'(t) .
$$
Show that the first fundamental form of $Σ$ is
$$
d s^2=d v^2+2 d v d t+\left(1+v^2\left|γ''(t)\right|^2\right) d t^2 .
$$

By direct calculation:
\begin{array}l
_t=γ'(t)+v γ''(t)\\
_v=γ'(t)\\
_v⋅_v=1\\
_t⋅_v=1\\
_t⋅_t=1+v^2{|γ''(t)|}^2\\
\end{array}
so the first fundamental form of $Σ$ is
$$
d s^2=d v^2+2 d v d t+\left(1+v^2\left|γ''(t)\right|^2\right) d t^2 .
$$
Last part

By considering a suitable plane curve, show that there is an open set in $Σ$ which is isometric to an open set in $ℝ^2$.

I am unsure about my proof:
By Curvature and plane curves there is a plane curve $β:ℝ → ℝ^2$ with $|β'(t)|=1$ and
$\left|β''(t)\right|=\left|γ''(t)\right|$.
Then the surface with parametrisation $(t, v)\mapsto β(t)+v β'(t)$ is an open set in $ℝ^2$.
The first fundamental form of the surface with parametrisation $(t, v)\mapsto β(t)+v β'(t)$ is
$$
d s^2=d v^2+2 d v d t+\left(1+v^2\left|β''(t)\right|^2\right) d t^2 .
$$
but $\left|β''(t)\right|=\left|γ''(t)\right|$, so $Σ$ is locally isometric to an open set in $ℝ^2$.
Is this a valid proof? Thanks!
